# Laravel ER diagram generator getAllModelsFromEachDirectory()

Tags: laravel, entity-relationship

When I try to follow the instruction here (https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-er-diagram-generator) I get the following error.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Argument 1 passed to BeyondCode\ErdGenerator\GenerateDiagramCommand::getAllModelsFromEachDirectory() must be of the type array, null given, called in vendor\beyondcode\laravel-er-diagram-generator\src\GenerateDiagramCommand.php on line 96
>
> ```
>  at vendor\beyondcode\laravel-er-diagram-generator\src\GenerateDiagramCommand.php:101
>      97|
>      98|         return $modelsFromDirectories;
>      99|     }
>     100|
>     101|     protected function getAllModelsFromEachDirectory(array $directories): Collection
>     102|     {
>     103|         return collect($directories)
>     104|             ->map(function ($directory) {
>     105|                 return $this->modelFinder->getModelsInDirectory($directory)->all();
> ```
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   BeyondCode\ErdGenerator\GenerateDiagramCommand::getAllModelsFromEachDirectory()
>         vendor\beyondcode\laravel-er-diagram-generator\src\GenerateDiagramCommand.php:96
>
> 2   BeyondCode\ErdGenerator\GenerateDiagramCommand::getModelsThatShouldBeInspected()
>         vendor\beyondcode\laravel-er-diagram-generator\src\GenerateDiagramCommand.php:57
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

I've already opened an issue in the repository.

Screen capture of the error:

[image]

Comment: Confirm you are using the latest version 1.4.0 of the library

Comment: Also if Ur using php artisan serve

Comment: Try to stop the server. Run php artisan config: cache. And restart the artisan sever

Comment: If no solution yet. Try this php artisan vendor:publish --provider=BeyondCode\\ErdGenerator\\ErdGeneratorServiceProvider.  Then repeat my second comment.

Comment: Thank you very much!  php artisan config: cache. solved the problem.

Comment: so i have added an answer you may review and vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting for others that may encounter same issue.

1. Confirm you are using the version 1.4.0 or greater of the library
2. Also if you're using `php artisan serve` try to stop the server. Run `php artisan config:cache`, and restart the artisan sever.

   Note that the reason why you might need to run `php artisan config:cache` is because Laravel does cache the app's configurations. if you changed or added new configurations you might explicitly need to clear the configuration cache so that Laravel can cache the new configurations.
3. If no solution yet. Try this
   `php artisan vendor:publish --provider=BeyondCode\\ErdGenerator\\ErdGeneratorServiceProvider`.
   Then repeat step 2.